# Переключение по кнопкам. JS

Tags: javascript

Как мне сделать переключение по кнопкам. Допустим у меня есть 3 кнопки: Москва, Санкт-Петербург, Киев. И я хочу что бы при нажатии на Москву снизу кнопки появлялась фотография Москвы, жму на Питер и фотография Москвы скрывается, и показывается Питер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const MOSCOW_IMG =
  'https://cdn2.tu-tu.ru/image/pagetree_node_data/1/055c4b01273eb986fead1a6db4c20e9f/';
const SPB_IMG =
  'https://wl-adme.cf.tsp.li/resize/728x/jpg/8fc/6a2/faaec65d1982763654c4302358.jpg';

const spb = document.getElementById('spb');
const moscow = document.getElementById('moscow');
const img = document.getElementById('city');

moscow.addEventListener('click', () => img.src = MOSCOW_IMG);
spb.addEventListener('click', () => img.src = SPB_IMG);
```

```html
<button id="spb">spb</button>
    <button id="moscow">moscow</button>
    <img
      src="https://cdn2.tu-tu.ru/image/pagetree_node_data/1/055c4b01273eb986fead1a6db4c20e9f/"
      alt="city"
      id="city"
    />
```